# Чи взаємозамінні "супутник" і "попутник"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Якщо орієнтуватись на СУМ, можна зробити висновок, що [**`супутник`**](http://sum.in.ua/s/suputnyk) і [**`попутник`**](http://sum.in.ua/s/poputnyk) - дуже близькі за значенням (принаймні, за першим) і можуть цілком бути взаємозамінними синонімами, хіба що окрім третього значення **`супутника`** як небесного тіла.

> **Супутник**, а, чол.
>
> 1. **Той, хто йде, їде, подорожує і т. ін. разом із ким-небудь**. *Ні княгиня Ольга, ні її супутники не нарікали, що поїхали через гори*
>      (Семен Скляренко, Святослав, 1959, 213); — *Мій супутник запропонував
>      піти до вагона-ресторану повечеряти* (Микола Трублаїні, Глиб. шлях,
>      1948, 98); *Всі розуміли, що вона хоче йти додому сама, без
>      супутників* (Олесь Донченко, V, 1957, 229);  * Образно. *Древній ліс,
>      — у тихому прибої, — Супутник твій до самого села* (Микола Нагнибіда,
>      Слово.., 1954, 27);
>
> **Попутник**, а, чол.
>
> 1. **Той, хто йде або їде разом з ким-небудь тим самим шляхом**. — *Як же тебе звати, мій попутнику? — Степаном назвали батьки, мабуть,
>      знали, що я степ любитиму, — знову хороше посміхнувся Степа*н
>      (Олександр Копиленко, Подарунок, 1956, 21); *— Воно й добре б трохи
>      відпочити та дочекатися чи то чумаків, чи то яких інших попутників*
>      (Зінаїда Тулуб, Людолови, I, 1957, 70).

Чи є все ж певні нюанси значень, що не відображені в СУМ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Як на мене, СУМ зобразив всі нюанси не тільки за описами, а також за прикладами.

**Супутник** вказується як особа, яка просто подорожує з кимось, цебто проводить з кимось весь чи майже (якщо щось трапилось) весь шлях.

А **попутник** – особа, яка з кимось має той самий [шлях](http://sum.in.ua/s/shljakh). Цебто [маршрути](http://sum.in.ua/s/marshrut) можуть бути зовсім різними у тих осіб.

Ось чому наступні пункти означень цих слів у словнику сильно різняться.

Але так, інколи *особа А* може бути і попутником, і супутником для *особи Б*, коли маршрут *особи Б* є частиною маршруту *особи А*.

---

Але це все було «як на мене». Вочевидь, що вся справа в префіксах **су-** i **по-**, тому нумо спробуймо технічніше. Для цього використаю наступні цитати:

> <sup>[Давні іменні префікси](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine44-12.pdf) (Вал. Г. Скляренко)</sup>
>
> Усі утворення з префіксом *па-* можна розділити на відіменні і віддієслівні, які утворилися від відповідних дієслів з префіксом *по-*.
>
> Іменні префікси разом з відповідними прийменниками і превербами (що стали пізніше дієслівними префіксами) походять від індоєвропейських форм *рō̆ «після, по», *sŏ́m «разом, з».
>
> *па-* означав [подібність](http://sum.in.ua/s/podibnistj);
>   *су-* виражав [спільність](http://sum.in.ua/s/spiljnistj);

> <sup>[Етимологічний словник української мови](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)</sup>
>
> **по**
>
> - псл. ро, ро-, пов’язане чергуванням голосних з ра- «па-»
> - споріднене з лит. ра- «по-», рó- «тс.», лтс. ра «під, через, пере-, на», прус. ра- «по-», ро-, лат. ро- «тс., пере-», ав. ра- «від, геть», алб. ра «без, знову», хет. рē «туди», а також з більш віддаленими гр. ἀπό «від», ἐπί «на», дінд. áра «геть, назад», áрі «теж, також; до цього»
> - частково пов’язане з іє. *роs «після, потім, слідом», до якого зводиться й псл. *роzdъ «пізній»
>
> ---
>
> **су-** (іменниковий префікс, що означає зв’язок, з’єднання або неповноту, в давніх іменних утвореннях типу *суві́й, су́в’язь, сугі́р’я, су́глинок, сугло́б, су́голосний, су́горб, сузі́р’я, су́кровиця, суми́рний, супе́рник, су́пісок, супря́га, сусі́д, сусі́к, суста́в, су́тінь, су́тки, суту́жний, сутя́га, суя́гна* і под.)
>
> - псл. sǫ- (‹ іє. *sōn-), пов’язане з дієслівними префіксами sъ-/sъn- (‹ іє. *sn̥-), укр. з- (префікс дієслів, що означає з’єднання, зосереджування), з (прийменник з орудн. в. для позначання сумісності)
> - споріднене з прус. san- «з-», sen- «з», лит. sán- «су-, з-», sąṛ́- «тс.», ст. sa- «з-», sù-, лтс. suo-, sa-, дінд. sam «з», sam- (‹ іє. *sem- «раз; одне»), sa- (‹ іє. *sm̥- «один»), ав. ham «з», ham- «з-», ha- «тс.», дісл. sam- «разом», гр. ὁμου̃, ἅμα «тс.», ἁ- «з-», ἀ-, ὀ- «тс.», лат. semel «один раз, раз; одразу; разом»
> - іє. *so-, *sōn-, *som-, *sem-, *sm̥-

[∎](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F#%D0%A9%D0%BE_%D1%96_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Схоже, що *попутник* може також мати значення близьке до [*переслідувач*](http://sum.in.ua/s/peresliduvach). Але, вважаю, таке наразі може використовуватись хіба що в художньому смислі.

---

Ще цікавий момент:

> <sup>[Словарь української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=41003) [(Борис Грінченко)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)</sup>
>
> **Попутник**, -ка, м. [Раст. Plantago major L.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) ЗЮЗО. І. 131.

Comment: Про *переслідувача* в якості *попутника* - цікава версія) Вочевидь, один з літературних прийомів. Згадати б який.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko не знаю, я знайшов фільм-жах [Попутник](https://goo.gl/q85CGA) та його [ремейк](https://goo.gl/vib7Ar), правда, я їх наче не бачив. А щодо ситуаціії в літературі, більш до цього підходить й мені що перше згадується, якщо не помиляюсь, книга [Любов до життя](https://goo.gl/G5zk5d), де хворий вовк ходить по пʼятах занедбаної людини, що опинилася посеред дикої природи. Й ті двоє хочуть вижити.

Comment: Схоже, що вживання слова або звороту мови в протилежному значенні - відома всім *іронія*. [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/ironija) (3), [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F). [іронія Шевченка](http://taras-shevchenko.in.ua/statti/satyra-ta-ironiya.html).

Comment: Та ні, все гаразд. Дякую за приклади. Дуже доречні.