# Значення, походження немов-префікса зу-

Tags: етимологія, префікс

Немов-префікс **зу-** є в [словах](http://sum.in.ua/vkazivnyk/zu), для прикладу: *зупинка* (але *спинитися*), *зухвалий* (але *хвалитися*), зустріч (*стрітити*) тощо.

Звісно, сей префікс не втрачається: є *зупинитися* і *зустрічати*.

Цікаво значення та роль префікса. Якщо є можливість — також походження.

Чи це просто різновидність префікса **з** зі своїми **зі** чи **зо**? Якщо так, то як закріпилися звуки **у**, **о**, **і**?

---

Подібні запитання

— [Чи взаємозамінні "супутник" і "попутник"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1509/)

Comment: https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%97-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D2%91%D1%96%D1%97-%D1%96-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8E

Comment: Що таке «немов-приросток»? «[Приросток](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2596)» бачу, а «немов-приросток»? Ви маєте на увазі, що це щось схоже на приросток, але не впевпені, що це справді є приросток з морфологічної точки зору?

Comment: Так, бо зараз це наче частина пня.

Answer (score 4):

Цікаве запитання. Справді, як дізнатися, що таке *зу-*: форма префікса *з-* із додатковою голосною для милозвучності чи стик префікса *з-* із префіксом *у-* (*в-*)?

Мені особисто здається, що *зі-* і *зо-* — то найчастіше голосна для милозвучності, а *зу* — найчастіше комбінація *з-* + *у-* (*в-*), адже маємо (іноді застарілі) слова [*упи́н* (*впин*)](http://sum.in.ua/s/upyn), *[ухвалити](http://sum.in.ua/s/ukhvaljuvaty)*, [*устрі́ти* (*встрі́ти*)](http://sum.in.ua/s/ustrinuty).

[«Етимологічний словник української мови» О. Мельничука](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) каже таке:

- *зуми́сне* ← *уми́сне*/*уми́сний* (споріднені до *мисль*) <sub>(том 4, ст. 17; том 3, ст. 466);</sub>
- *зухва́лий* ← польські zuchwały, **zupwać* (*z-* + **upwać*) ← праслов'янське **upъvati* <sub>(том 2, ст. 283);</sub>
- *зустрі́ти*, *зу́стріч*, *устрі́ча* («зустріч»), *устрі́ч* («назустріч»), *стрі́ти*, *стрі́ча* ← праслов'янське **sъ-rěsti* < **sǔ-rēttei* <sub>(том 5, ст. 446);</sub>
- *зу́пи́н*, *зу́пи́нка*, *зупини́ти*, *упина́тися* («відмовлятися»), *упня́ти* («зв'язати»), *упі́н* («стрічковий канат для прив'язування»), *упо́н* («прив'язь»), *упо́на* («пута, стрічка, мотузок»), *уп'я́тий* («прив'язаний») ← праслов'янські *peͅti*, *pьnoͅ* <sub>(том 4, ст. 651).</sub>

Тобто, хоча словник прямо каже про похождення *зу<щось>* від *у<щось>* лише у перших двох випадках (причому в першому випадку *у-* є окремим префіксом, а в другому — можливо, навіть частиною кореня), велика кількість споріднених слів вигляду *у<щось>* у третьому і четверному випадках складає враження, що я правий у всіх цих випадках (*зу…* ← *у…* ← *…*).

(Хоча із *зо-* є теж багато випадків, коли *-о-* є явно початком наступної морфеми, а не просто голосною для зручності читання: *зобижати*, *зобов'язаний*, *зображення*.)